# Three state checkbox with angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm new to angularjs and I'm having a very difficult time attempting to create a directive to implement a three-state checkbox. I'd like to create a two-way binding between the isolated scope variable in my directive and my controller scope variable. Obviously somehow I've cocked it up.

My goal is to be able to update the state of the checkbox in the dom whenever the state variable gets updated in the controller, and to update the state variable in the controller whenever the user clicks on the checkbox.

After snooping around on the google machine i decided I needed to set up a $watch on my directive attribute (my knowledge of which is tenuous as best). I haven't been able to get that to work. It never gets called when my variable is changed from the controller. Below is a snippet of my markup and the meat of my directive. See my fiddle below for the details.

```
<input checkbox-three-state='item.state' type='checkbox' /> 

directive('checkboxThreeState', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            state: '=checkboxThreeState'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                // update the controller scope
            });

            scope.$watch(attributes.checkboxThreeState, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                // update the dom
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I think I have my other objective (update controller scope on click) down.

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevietaytay/h4xkqnnj/).

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason why you're opting for a checkbox with an indeterminate state, as opposed to a traditional multi-value input, such as a dropdown/radio set?

Comment: Seem to be trying to reinvent `ng-model` and `ng-change`

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly. Display Name, `ng-model` binds the data back to the scope by default. There's no need to reinvent the wheel here. What may be better, if you're hoping for a click to change state effect for multiple states, Radio + some CSS hackery may be a better option. Knowing more about the use case will allow us to give you better advice.

Comment: also note that events outside of angular core that update scope like your click handler need to notify angular to update view. There isn't much in the way of form controls that you can't do already with core angular... learn the angular ways first ... every form element directive  is listed in the api. In short...what you are doing makes no sense

Comment: This is being used to implement a tree, where checked indicates all children checked, unchecked indicates all children unchecked, and indeterminate indicates some children checked. Ng-model won't do that for me, and the client always wants what they want, so unless anyone can tell me how to do this without reinventing the wheel i'll be trying to do just that.

Comment: @DisplayName Ahh, then perhaps this fiddle can point you in the right direction. http://jsfiddle.net/johnwun/wnjze03h/ Since you didn't point to a tree, I assumed you meant doing something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fqkd4qz5/ (cycling through various options on a single checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that my question was poorly framed, it really should have been asking why the watch I set up in my directive wasn't working. Now i know that I was telling it to watch the wrong scope property, one that didn't actually exist. Mea culpa. Previously I was telling it to watch my directive attribute -- I had just copied somebody else's example, because I'm a monkey.

```
scope: {
    state: '=checkboxThreeState'
},
link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
    // other stuff

    scope.$watch(attributes.checkboxThreeState, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        // update the dom
    });
}
```

After doing a lot more snooping -- I don't know why this isn't spelled out more ubiquitously for idiots like myself -- I recognized that I had to indicate which property on my scope to watch, namely 'state'.

```
scope.$watch('state', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // do my jam
});
```

Now that i've figured that out it seems entirely obvious, but I can be pretty dense.

Here's my now working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevietaytay/h4xkqnnj/12/).

**Updated Question**

Why doesn't the watch function in my directive get fired when the controller changes the value of the variable that gets passed into my directive?

**Answer Summary:**

The watch function should watch a variable that actually exists on your directive scope variable. This is never spelled out in the documentation and although it may be obvious to most, I didn't put that together immediately. I was under the impression -- and to be fair to myself there are a lot of really bad examples out there that severely misled me -- that I should be watching my directive attribute, whose value comes from the controller scope.